# Sql retrieve parent and its child

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table

```
Id      |   Name    | ParentId
1       | Parent    | 0
2       | Subparent | 1
3       | Child     | 2
```

What query to retrieve one of its parent name (if any) and its parent sub (child) name whenever I input the ID, so for example

input ID = 1,
ouput = Parent | Subparent | Child

Input ID = 2,
Output = Parent | Subparent | Child

Input ID = 3,
Output = Subparent | Child

Comment: Many solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursive-query+sql+postgresql)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i will tag postgres then, thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701519/5962802